# How i can change instead of default datetime with value from database?

Tags: php, yii

Hi Everyone,

```
  <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'hosting_date'); 

        if($model->hosting_date != null) 
        {   

                $dateString = $model->hosting_date;
                $date = new DateTime($dateString);
                $interval = new DateInterval('P7D'); // Periode of 7 days
                $date->add($interval); // $date is not 7 days ahead

                    $this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
                                            'id'=>'datepicker',
                                            'model'=>$model,
                                            'attribute'=>'hosting_date',
                                            'name'=>'hosting_date',
                                            'value'=>$date->format('Y-m-d'),
                                            'htmlOptions'=>array('required'=>'required' , 'value'=>date('Y-m-d')),
                                    ));  
            $this->endWidget();



        }
```

Above codes are from my project's update page. I want to see instead of current date, lastly added to the database value but these codes don't work. How can i do this? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: you can store in the databse when the record was created (for example created_at) and then sort on that field and take the first 1.

Comment: Thanks for your precious comment but i must do this manual. It will work for company and they must enter the value manually. You can think like reservation system for hotel. @Nicolas